# Slow down the text fading on scroll down in squarespace gallery page

Tags: javascript, css, squarespace

I have a website in squarespace. There is a gallery page which has some text and when scrolled down it shows some pictures and text fades away, all i want is to slow the fading transition effect of the page, anyone can help? i tried to add the following script in the header code injection but it didn't work

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">



window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('#collection-5aa2fea971c10b74be7193dd', {duration: 1500});

</script>
```

Comment: There are two pieces of information that are helpful in regards to questions related to Squarespace sites: 1) What template are you using? and 2) is AJAX enabled (if the template supports it)? As a bonus, a link to the site in question along with the temporary view-only access password (if applicable for sites in trial-mode) can help get your question answered. Consider editing your question to include this information, as applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`sr.reveal('#collection-5aa2fea971c10b74be7193dd', {delay: 1500});`

Comment: can you please tell me where to add this code, specifically ? its not working in page header code injection. also one more thing to mention the heading is fading already, i just want to slow it down,

Comment: You can add this at the end of your document `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     window.sr = ScrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('#collection-5aa2fea971c10b74be7193dd', {delay: 1500});
}, false);`
Note the use of `delay` instead of `duration`

Comment: is there any other way, using CSS or something?

Comment: I suggest you use this link and make a JSbin example so we can understand exactly why it is not working